# Problema ao usar 'Google Fonts'

Tags: css, css-font-face

Gostaria usar uma fonte da Google sem precisar de Conexão (internet). Vi que o `@font-face` tem esse poder. Basta apenas baixar a fonte em um dos formatos (preferi o `.EOT` por também ser aceito pelo IE Browser) e declarar da seguinte forma:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'VT323';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/VT323-Regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/VT323-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(‘../fonts/VT323-Regular.ttf’) format(‘truetype’);
}
```

Onde `url` é onde está localizado o arquivo da fonte.
E para fazer uso dela deve-se apenas chamar o `font-family`, obviamente, com o nome declarado no `@font-face`:

```
.home-text {
    font-family: 'VT323', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

**Contudo, ainda não consigo gozar da fonte VT323.** Os códigos acima são originais do meu projeto. Segue abaixo a estrutura dos diretórios dos arquivos (informação adicional):

[image: estrutura de diretórios]

Comment: Tenta usar todos os formatos, isso ajuda até na compatibilidade

Comment: Tentou adicionar o `font-weight: 400` também no `.home-text`?

Comment: Tentei agora e não mudou o cenário.

Comment: Tenta converter a font para o formato web fonts, uso esse site para converter http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: tente usar 'fonts/VT323-regula...' ao invés de '../fonts/VT323-regula...'

Comment: @Leandro, Já usei esse site pra converter de '.ttf' para '.eot', não faz sentido converter novamente.

George, não mudou o cenário. Existe um classe nesse mesmo arquivo '.css' que usa um arquivo externo no mesmo nível que essa fonte. O 'source' do mesmo estava da forma que eu 'repliquei' no código da dúvida.

Comment: Funciona se você pôr a fonte no mesmo diretório que o arquivo CSS (e mudar a declaração ```font-face``` pra refletir isso)? Qual seria a situação aonde você usaria isso? Seria possível instalar a fonte no sistema? Se for, será que não é mais prático dessa forma? Qual navegador você está usando?

Comment: Já tentou mudar os nomes das fontes para letra pequena e actualizar, obviamente, na url? Segundo a W3Schools, fontes com letras maiúsculas podem ter comportamentos estranhos, especialmente em IE. Reparei que, na última declaração da propriedade src tem **‘** em vez de **'**. Pode não ser nada, mas mantém a consistência. **EDIT** Reparei agora que no código tem a fonte com o nome VT323-Regular.eot mas na imagem com os directórios tem o nome VT323-regular.eot. Altere para reflectir a realidade, se não for um erro ortográfico aquando a criação da imagem.

Comment: @josepostiga a [w3schools não é uma boa referência](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: Coloquei os arquivos na pasta do CSS e fiz as devidas alterações inclusive renomeá-las para minúsculo. Nenhuma alteração no cenário.*** Acho que esse é um daqueles erros tão óbvios que não é fácil de enxergar... rsr

Comment: O Google Fonts detecta o user agent na hora de carregar as fontes: baixou o código usando mais de um navegador? Ainda, se o código for realmente o original, por que tem ‘aspas curvas’ nele?

Comment: @PhellipeLins recentemente resolvi um problema parecido. A solução está nas Respostas abaixo. De qualquer forma copiei e colei seu CSS num arquivo e fiz um hexdump -x e o caracter ' (plic) usado na sua solução na seção `@font-face` parece não estar correto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o [SkyFonts](http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts/google?showGoogleFontsDialog) permite você sincronizar fontes do GoogleFonts com seu Desktop.

No MAC OS X o SkyFonts baixa os fontes para a pasta ~/Library/Application Support/skyfonts-google e você pode copiar para a pasta **/css/fonts** do seu site.

Obviamente você não precisa usar SkyFonts, basta fazer o Download. Eu uso por comodidade na gestão de Fonts nos meus Computadores.

Agora ao problema do VT323. O procedimento abaixo eu testei no Chrome e Safari.

Crie um arquivo css em **/css/vt323.css** com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'VT323';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('VT323'), local('VT323-Regular'), url(VT323-Regular.ttf) format('ttf');
}
```

No seu HTML coloque as seguintes linhas de código no `<head>`:

```
<link href="/css/vt323.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: VT323;
  }
</style>
```

Abaixo uma ilustração de como pesquisar e sincronizar o fonte VT323 com seu Desktop usando o SkyFonts.

[image: Usando o SkyFonts]

Comment: Mas isso seria tudo feito localmente?

Comment: Na minha proposta de solução eliminamos a dependência do usuário com uma conexão com a Internet para baixar os fontes de um site tal como o  http://fonts.googleapis.com. Recentemente tive de fazer isso para evitar que a página congelasse numa Intranet devido a queda do link com a Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou o [IcoMoon?](http://icomoon.io/)

Tem ótimos recursos para editar e baixar arquivos de fontes.
Eu uso primariamente para criar ícones como fontes mas acredito que possa ser usado como fontes para escrever textos (bem, na pior das hipoteses você terá que "desenhar" as letras que você vai precisar).

Tem bons exemplos e talvez você possa usar como referência.

Comment: Não pretendo driblar o problema, quero resolve-lo!